# How to make a communication between Arduino, Web app and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino

I'm making a project where temperature and humidity levels are sensored by Arduino and send those data to AWS with ESP-8266-01s. At the same time, those data are also shown on the web application (it may be on Node.js/Java, etc.).

So what I'm asking is how the architecture should be. What is the best practice? Does AWS also provide a web app where I can use it for both database cloud as a web application or should I make a separate project as a web app to connect to AWS?

I searched on Google but the only answers I can find are two ways: Arduino and AWS without another aspect connected to it in my case the web app.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) protocol.

Components required -

1. `Pubsubclient.h` library on esp8266 that will be used to publish temp and humidity data to MQTT Broker on AWS
2. [mosquitto](https://mosquitto.org/) MQTT broker setup on AWS used to accept data from esp8266
3. Python script that will subscribe to data from the mosquitto broker and dumps into any database(my suggestion is [influxdb](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/))
4. Graphing platform to query database and display visual timeseries-graphs(my suggestion [grafana](https://grafana.com))

Use AWS only for purchasing a virtual machine. Rest can be taken care using open-source Platforms.
Assuming you want to display graphs of temperature and humidity, Using grafana is the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find a silver bullet here. A proper architecture for your case depends on many things and there can be different approaches with their own pros and cons.
There are many aspects to cover including connectivity, security, update, availability, costs.

Usually IoT devices are not connected directly to the cloud, because they don't have a constant connection, or any network connection. There is a hub (or middleware) that collects data from sensors/devices and send them to the cloud for processing.
But many cloud vendors provide some out of the box complex solutions here (including [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/iot/)).
I listed just examples.